# Moveit Commander Plan Fail

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rospy and moveit_commander to control a robot. It works wonderfully, except I cannot find a way in the API to handle a path planning failure. The `MoveGroupCommander.plan()` method does not seem to expose any value that indicates failure in python. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338658/moveit-commander-plan-fail/) by [rklutz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49792/rklutz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the plan fails, the `RobotTrajectory` is empty, so you can check it as described [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/304494/can-planning-success-be-checked-in-the-python-movegroupcommander/):

```
plan = move_group.plan()
if plan.joint_trajectory.points:  # True if trajectory contains points
  move_success = move_group.execute(plan)
else:
  rospy.logerr("Trajectory is empty. Planning was unsuccessful.")
```

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3